# How to check for undefined value in jQuery - Can not read property error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a value if it exists within the json feed. Since it sometimes is not the case, I do rececive the following error:

```
(index):703 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price_min' of null
    at Object.success ((index):703)
    at i (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:4)
```

My code looks like this:

```
 if (obj.stats.price_min !== undefined){
      $('#price_from').val(obj.stats.price_min);
 }
```

Is this not the propper way to test for undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely trying to access a non-existing property will raise an error, you should check its existence using `obj.hasOwnProperty`:

```js
var obj = {stats: null};

if (obj.hasOwnProperty('stats') && obj.stats && obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_min')) {
  $('#price_from').val(obj.stats.price_min);
}

obj = {stats: {price_min: '200'}}

if (obj.hasOwnProperty('stats') && obj.stats && obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_min')) {
  $('#price_from').val(obj.stats.price_min);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price_from" />
```

You could also do it by checking against `undefined`, but first you should make sure it's not `null`:

```js
var obj = {stats: null};

if (obj.stats !== undefined && obj.stats && obj.stats.price_min !== undefined) {
  $('#price_from').val(obj.stats.price_min);
}

obj = {stats: {price_min: '200'}}

if (obj.stats !== undefined && obj.stats && obj.stats.price_min !== undefined) {
  $('#price_from').val(obj.stats.price_min);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price_from" />
```

Comment: I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of null after implementing "  if (obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_min')){" - I am using jQuery 1.12.0

Comment: @merlin do this `if (obj.hasOwnProperty('stats') && obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_min')) {`, like in my answer.

Comment: I did, same result.

Comment: @merlin is `obj` defined?

Comment: Yes, but: "stats":null}

Comment: @merlin then check for it first, like this `if (obj.hasOwnProperty('stats') && obj.stats && obj.stats.hasOwnProperty('price_min')) `. Check the edit.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.